# what is a vivid knowledge base

Tags: knowledge-management

I read in an exam about knowledge representation the question:

> What is a vivid knowledge base?

And I wonder about the answer. Google only gives me some links to books which I can buy about it or some CiteSeerX articles. Wikipedia also doesn't know anything about it.

Is there any good online article?

Is "vivid knowledge" a common term or is another term more common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another definition:

a first-order KB is **vivid** :<=>

for some finite set of positive function-free ground literals KB+ :

KB = KB+ ∪ 'Negations' ∪ 'Domain closure' ∪ 'Unique names'

---

And another one:

a KB is **vivid** :<=>

KB is a *complete* and *consistent* set of literals (for some language)

---

To specify *complete*:

a KB is **complete** :<=> there is no formular α such that KB ⊭ α and KB ⊭ ¬α

---

To specify *consistent*:

a KB is **not consistent** :<=> its negation is a *tautology*

Answer (score 3):

#### Vivid Knowledge Representation and Reasoning

[image]

Comment: Yes that is what I meant by the book links. But is there a more complete article? This is only the first page and you cannot access the other page.

Comment: Also, I don't exactly understand the content. What exactly is a disjunctive knowledge base? What is vivid reasoning? And a relational database is not a knowledge base - the whole point of KR is to have a base of knowledge which usually gives you an infinite amount of facts you can conclude from it - that is the difference to a database.

Answer (score 1):

This article explains it a bit better:
[Vivid Knowledge and Tractable Reasoning: Preliminary Report](http://dli.iiit.ac.in/ijcai/IJCAI-89-VOL-2/PDF/048.pdf)

As far as I understand it, a vivid knowledge base is a knowledge base with a closed world assumption.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a collection of facts and rules is called a
**knowledge base**

Comment: But what is a **vivid** knowledge base?

Comment: vivid knowledge is a kind of knowledge representation. The general idea is it implies the interpretation.

Comment: You are supposed to write the answer as an answer, not as a comment. (See general StackOverflow guidelines.) Also, your answer is a bit vague. You should give some more details. A mathematical exact definition would be nice.